# Using jettyRunWar or jettyRun in Gradle with a Spring Boot app results in just a directory listing in the browser

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot

I'm using Gradle and Spring Boot for the first time.  I decided to create a project that actually builds a WAR archive and I'm using the Gradle Jetty plugin.  If I run the jettyRun or jettyRunWar tasks, in my browser all I'm seeing is a directory listing, not my actual application.

For example, the jettyRunWar task results in a directory listing like this:

```
META-INF/
WEB-INF/
dist/
```

The dist/ directory contains my static files.

Maybe I'm missing something fundamental since I'm using Gradle and Spring Boot for the first time.

I'm trying to test my app while making changes to my static files without restarting the app.  Here is my build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:0.5.0.M6"
    }
}

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "idea"
apply plugin: "spring-boot"
apply plugin: "war"

war {
    baseName = "mis-support-client"
    version =  "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    includes = ["dist/**"]
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.11" 

    compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:0.5.0.M7") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:0.5.0.M7"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:0.5.0.M7"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:0.5.0.M7" 
    compile "javax.inject:javax.inject:1"
    compile "org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.12"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.1"
    compile "commons-io:commons-io:2.4"
}

task wrapper (type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = "1.8"
}
```

Comment: Please add your gradle jetty configuration or whole gradle.build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try `./gradlew bootRun` instead? Normal Spring Boot project has server embedded for easier usage :)

This task requires gradle plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
```

### Features

> Embed Tomcat or Jetty directly (no need to deploy WAR files)

### Task

```
Execution tasks
---------------
bootRun - Run the executable JAR/WAR
```

Comment: It worked using the embedded before, but I'm trying to create a WAR instead so I can deploy the application to an existing Tomcat installation.  I followed the guide on spring.io for doing this and am trying to use the Gradle Jetty plugin just for testing like I've done in the past when using Maven.

Comment: I'm looking for the same behaviour as the Maven Jetty plugin where I don't have to rebuild the archive every time I make a change to my JS client side code. The Maven jetty:run command allows me to make changes to my client side code and they're reflected immediately in the running app.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Can you put this additional information into question? :)

Comment: The Boot gradle plugin is supposed to support editing of static resources as well. Did you try it?

Comment: No, I didnt. I work with REST project only. But Im sure this should work.

Comment: I've posted my build.gradle above.  When I try "bootRun" I get an error saying "Task 'bootRun' not found in root project 'client'"

Comment: add `apply plugin: 'spring-boot'` to `build.gradle`

Comment: Actually, I think I just fixed it by switching the spring-boot plugin version from 0.5.0.M6 to 0.5.0.M7.  Was bootRun only added to M7?

Comment: Strangely, now I have a new problem.  My static files are located in src/main/webapp and are generated by a Yeoman Backbone generator.  If I make changes to my JS source files and run the "grunt" command, the updated JS isn't available in my app when using "bootRun".  The grunt command minifies amongst other things and stores the static files in src/main/webapp/dist.  That directory is copied to my WAR during "clean build".  But during "bootRun" it doesn't seem to recognize changes.

Comment: Please add new question, I will look into it.

Comment: Ok, I've posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047061/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-bootrun-task-not-recognizing-when-static-files-are-gen