# Spring Boot Gradle plugin bootRun task not recognizing when static files are generated by Yeoman and updated with grunt

Tags: backbone.js, gradle, spring-boot

I have a Backbone app generated with Yeoman.  Using the Spring Boot Gradle plugin along with the bootRun task to run the app, when I make changes to my JS source and run Grunt to recompile/minify my source into the dist directory, those changes aren't reflected in the currently running bootRun task.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:0.5.0.M7"
    }
}

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "idea"
apply plugin: "spring-boot"
apply plugin: "war"

war {
    baseName = "mis-support-client"
    version =  "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    includes = ["dist/**"]
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.11" 

    compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:0.5.0.M7") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:0.5.0.M7"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:0.5.0.M7"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:0.5.0.M7" 
    compile "javax.inject:javax.inject:1"
    compile "org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.12"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.1"
    compile "commons-io:commons-io:2.4"
}

task wrapper (type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = "1.8"
}
```

Here's my customer resource handlers for mapping the "dist" directory.

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/bower_components/**", "/scripts/**", "/styles/**", "/fonts/**", "/font/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/dist/bower_components/", "/dist/scripts/", "/dist/styles/", "/dist/bower_components/bootstrap/fonts/", "/dist/bower_components/font-awesome/font/")
                .setCachePeriod(315569126);
    }
```

Comment: Please attach your gradle.build

Comment: Gradle and Spring don't know anything about the generated resources or the process you use to create them. I believe you should be able to edit static resources in `src/main/resources/static` (etc.) and see those changes in a running app (maybe you can confirm that?).

Comment: I'll give that a try.  I'm still new to both Gradle and Boot, so this is just the process of figuring out how things work.  Will post feedback after I've tried your suggestion.

Comment: OK good. If grunt generates resources in well-known locations we can maybe detect changes for you (or allow you to configure it in Gradle). A complete, minimal sample project would be a useful starting point if you could share something on github (or similar).

Comment: I've created a repo on Bitbucket https://bitbucket.org/pgrimard/spring-boot-backbone/overview

Comment: On a related note, I have another repo which accomplishes this, but it doesn't use Spring Boot nor Gradle.  https://bitbucket.org/pgrimard/spring-security-csrf-backbone

Comment: It didn't seem to work when I put the generated sources in src/main/resources.  I have a custom resource handler that attempts to map the "dist" directory under src/main/resources as well.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are trying to do with the client-side code. I'm not at all familiar with the tools you are using so could you add a README to the first repo like the one in the second so I know how to run your app?

Comment: I've just added the readme which includes some additional links if you need assistance installing the tools.

Comment: Thanks, great (you forgot to say that I needed Ruby and Compass, but Grunt told me that). I got your app to run, and verified that resources served from `src/main/resources` can be reloaded, but only if I use Maven (here's an [issue about that](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/225)).

Comment: I had to modify the app a bit, but not in a way that I think changed any functionality. I don't know if "/dist" is a conventional location that everyone loves with Grunt, but it's much simpler from a Spring Boot perspective to put static resources in "/public" (or "/static"), so I did that and removed your redundant `WebConfig`.  I also changed the `SecurityConfig` so the login redirect is to `/login.html`. Shall I push it up to github?

Comment: Great!  Yes if you can push it up, I'll have a look.  Thanks!

Comment: The /dist directory I believe is a convention for where compiled/minified sources are placed.  I believe it's configurable though from the Gruntfile.js source, so I can play around with that.

Comment: I modified your Gruntfile to put the resources in `/public`: see [here](https://github.com/scratches/gh-225).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45284/discussion-between-dave-syer-and-patrick-grimard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your app to run, and verified that resources served from `src/main/resources` can be reloaded, but until today only if I use Maven (here's an [issue about that](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/225)). The github issue is fine by me if you want to discuss further.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Yeoman plugin that does exactly the same thing, but with Maven.

We have a Spring Boot backend, built with Maven, which works great with an AngularJS frontend, built with Grunt.

You can find this Yeoman generator here: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster